# jQuery multiple overlayed divs

Tags: jquery, html, overlay

i have the following jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#showContent').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("body").append("<div id='lyricsOverlay'></div>");
        $("#lyricsOverlay").height($(document).height()); 
        $('#lyrics').show();
        $('#lyricsOverlay').click(function() { 
            $('#lyrics').hide();
            $('#lyricsOverlay').remove();
        });
    });
})
```

Which shows an overlayed div, with the rest of the page blurred.

Works perfectly with:

```
<a href="#" id="showContent">Lyrics...</a>
```

My **problem**:

Inside the page I have many links which I want to behave just like first one. So, how can I implement something like:

```
<a href="#" id="showContent0">Lyrics...</a>
<a href="#" id="showContent1">Lyrics...</a>
...
```

And make the two or more of them work?

Something like:

```
**i = GET i from the link?** 
$('#showContent.**i**').click(function(e) {
```

This works partially, allows opening, but prevents overlay from closing ever again...

```
$((this)).click(function(e) {
```

Obviously the sintax above is not correct, I have no idea on how to do it...

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do it this way:

```
$('[id^=showContent]')
```

This will select all elements which id begins with showContent.

Comment: Thanks, that does exactly what I needed! I'll accept when stackoverflow allows me to! ;)

Answer (score 0):

download this lib i've developed something like this and made it easy to use, just call the `jloading()` and `jHide()` methods
https://github.com/gemy21ce/ajax-submit.git

Answer (score 0):

you can also use Qtip2 which is very highly customizable. you can find it here http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/demos/#tips it is same as there are too many overlays on the same windows and also you can make them as per your requirement. Qtip2's documentation is here http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/docs/

hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks, found the solution with the first answer. Although this is not what I need, maybe it'll be useful for other things!